tanstack sorting arrow function call onClick not working but when calling directly on onClick , its works , why?
This doesn't work:
onClick={() => {
  header.column.getToggleSortingHandler();
}}

However if I invoke it like this then it works - why?
onClick={
  header.column.getToggleSortingHandler()
}

I was expecting the arrow function to give similar results.
